# Android SD card on emulator writing fails with IOException EROFS (Read-only filesystem), have correct permission

Tags: java, android, android-emulator, sd-card

My android app can't write a file to the AVD's SD card, here's the code:

```
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    Log.w("sdcard", "root.canWrite() = " + root.canWrite());

    try {           
        File myFile = new File(root + File.pathSeparator + "mysdfile.txt");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append("testing testing 123");
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.w("ExternalStorage", "Error writing", e);
    }
```

`root.canWrite()` returns true, then this exception is raised:

```
java.io.IOException: open failed: EROFS (Read-only file system)
```

The manifest file has the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission (direct child of manifest):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I've also tried remounting the SD card in the AVD shell using:

```
mount -o remount rw /mnt/sdcard
```

...but to no avail. The AVD also has the "SD card support" flag set. Not sure what to do from here, any ideas?

Comment: the emulator's running version 4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To anyone interested, the problem was that I had made an sdcard.iso image and had eclipse passing that to the AVD as the -sdcard command line argument. For whatever reason, the image was read-only. Fixed the problem by clearing the command line args and editing the AVD to start with a new sd card of size 512mb, rather than a file.

Answer (score 5):

Starting from Honeycomb, Android devices by default do not allow third-party apps from writing to external removable storage. You can check this by firing up your adb shell, go to /system/etc/permissions/platform.xml, and look for this line:

```
<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
</permission>
```

Third party apps are not part of "sdcard_rw" group, instead they're part of "media_rw".
If your phone is rooted (your emulator should be), you can modify the platform.xml file to add another group that has this permission. It should look like this:

```
<permission name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" >
    <group gid="sdcard_rw" />
    <group gid="media_rw" />
</permission>
```

Some manufacturers (I know Samsung does) that still have SD Card slots on their phones fixed this themselves, but not even Nexus 7 or GNex has this fixed by default.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Stupid question, but how do I go about changing platform.xml permanently? I can modify platform.xml as you've shown using `adb remount` and `adb push ..` but the change doesn't persist after restarting. Running the app after the change results in the same error, so I'm guessing this file is only read at boot-time?

Comment: unfortunately, it looks like the emulator's resetting the changes on restart. on an actual device it doesn't do that. sorry, can't help you further

Comment: Thank you! That helped me in quite a different case - I have had a 4.1 tablet with permissions mixed up.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i have mistake with the slash. while specifying "Additional Emulator Command Line Options" in eclipse

Actually it should be -sdcard C:/Kamal/sdcard/emulator_sdcard

and i was putting -sdcard C:\Kamal\sdcard\emulator_sdcard

Then after restarting the Eclipse & Emulator it works.

Answer (score 0):

> `try {`
>
> ```
>               InputStream inputStream2 = openFileInput("database.sqlite3");
>               File outFile =new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "database15.sqlite3");
>               outFile.createNewFile();
>               OutputStream out= new FileOutputStream(outFile);
>               byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
>               int len;
>               while((len = inputStream2.read(buf))> 0)
>               {
>                   out.write(buf);
>               }
>               out.close();
>               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),getFilesDir().toString()+"Done", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>       } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
>           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"file not found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>       } catch (IOException e) {
>           Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
>       }
> ```

Comment: No finally block for the close, Toast have to be on UI thread and I/O operation should be on worker thread... poor code :(