# android adb push not working

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

My problem is i can write files on sd card in emulator but i find the solution to this problem in stack overflow  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13337196/android-sd-card-on-emulator-writing-fails-with-ioexception-erofs-read-only-file) to implement that you have to add a group media_rw under android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE in platform.xml so for i successfully pulled the xml file but after editing the file i can't push that file so when i am pushing it gives the below error

```
[Java is awesome]:~$ adb push platform.xml /system/etc/permissions/ 
failed to copy 'platform.xml' to '/system/etc/permissions//platform.xml': Read-only file system
```

to overcome this i remount the adb and again i tried i gives the below error

```
[Java is awesome]:~$ adb remount
remount succeeded
[Java is awesome]:~$ adb push platform.xml /system/etc/permissions/
failed to copy 'platform.xml' to '/system/etc/permissions//platform.xml': Out of memory
```

so how can push the file or is there any alternative that can enable editing of file with in the adb shell
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the /system partition size accordingly to account for the extra bytes in the file:

You can do this with the following command:

```
emulator -partition-size <size>
```

Where  is the size depends on your system image plus the extra bytes.